# how to solve glusterfs GFID split-brain

Tags: glusterfs

I have a glusterfs of three servers and after a bit of troubleshooting i concluded that a file has a gfid split-brain.

```
**Server1**
# file: srv/glusterfs/gbrick/file1
trusted.afr.dirty=0x000000000000000000000000
trusted.afr.shared-client-1=0x000000050000000100000000
trusted.bit-rot.version=0x020000000000000059b166800006516b
trusted.gfid=0x4ca01cfe117c4115a049ae108d58271b


**Server2**
# file: srv/glusterfs/gbrick/file1
trusted.afr.dirty=0x000000000000000000000000
trusted.afr.shared-client-1=0x000000050000000100000000
trusted.bit-rot.version=0x020000000000000059b166800006516b
trusted.gfid=0xa8a1718e0bd64783b535b6ff0e26699a


**Server3**
# file: srv/glusterfs/gbrick/file1
trusted.afr.dirty=0x000000000000000000000000
trusted.afr.shared-client-1=0x000000050000000100000000
trusted.bit-rot.version=0x020000000000000059b166800006516b
trusted.gfid=0x4ca01cfe117c4115a049ae108d58271b
```

It looks like the `trusted.gfid` on server2 is different compared to server1 and server3. Is there any way to tell glusterfs to update the file on server2 with the one of server1 (or server3) ?

Answer (score 0):

from what i read at https://staged-gluster-docs.readthedocs.io/en/release3.7.0beta1/Features/heal-info-and-split-brain-resolution/

'Note that entry/gfid split-brain resolution is not supported.'

but if you find this page like me with non-gfid splitbrain scenario - these can be healed.